# How to trigger feature files from TestRunner that are present in a different project

Tags: karate

I have 2 projects A and B. In project A, i have 1 feature file named feature1.feature. In project B, i have TestRunner class. I want to trigger feature1.feature of project A from TestRunner of Project B. Is there any way to do this without giving absolute path.

Comment: if the linked answer does not help, please assume this is not supported